# Jquery How to change the TEXT_NODE

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery and with a question that might be confusing. But thanks a lot for checking this. I want to modify the text within an element. for example:

```
<div class="testit">test it for no.1 and test.com <img=...> <a href="http://test.com/">test it</a></div>
<div class="testit">another test for No.2 and test2.com and test.com <img=...> <a href="http://test2.com/">test2</a> Another description</div>
```

I would like to use JQuery to modify the "some text conents" part in each class "testit" element but I do want to keep other tag elements unchanged. For example: the desired output will be:

```
<div class="testit">test it for no.1 and <a href="http://test.com">test.com</a> <img=...> <a href="http://test.com">test it</a></div>
<div class="testit">another test for No.2 and <a href="http://test2.com">test2.com</a> and <a href="http://test.com">test.com</a> <img=...> <a href="http://test2.com/">test2</a> Another description</div>
```

The follow JQuery can get the original contents but cannot modify them. Can you advice me how to change the jquery program?

```
var getTextNodesIn = function(el) {
  return jQuery(el).find().andSelf().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
  });};
var current_text=getTextNodesIn(this);
current_text.text('new contents here');
```

Comment: Change `jQuery(el).find().andSelf()` to `jQuery(el)`. Calling `.find` without an argument returns an empty jQuery object.

Comment: And you are returning text nodes so set its node value... Ex: `current_text[0].nodeValue` If you have many node loop through them and set it. http://jsfiddle.net/DJ8j6/

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear, I updated on the post with a little more details.

Comment: Don't your just want a regular expression to replace a node content ? If so, see : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+regular+expression+to+replace+a+node+content

Answer (score 0):

Added a Regex to detect if the string contains the value

```
var count = 1;
$('.testit').each(function () {
//check if the test string is found
var str = $(this).text();
var patt = new RegExp("test.com");
var res = patt.test(str);
if(res){
    $(this).text("new text contents No." + count); 
    count++; 
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for your quick answer. I updated my post again since my previous version was given too simple and did reflect all I need. I would like to replace some keywords to hyperlinks while the existing hyperlinks, img, and media links will not be affected. The function I tried was actually within the .each(). I am not sure if I am clear enough or not. Thanks. Jay

Comment: @user3103660 I don't understand, nor do I see a change in your post.

Comment: if it is a pure test.com text then it needs to become <a href="http://test.com">test.com</a>. And if it is already <a href="http://test.com"> format then don't change.